# Proportional Editing : where is the center of the circle/sphere?

Tags: proportional-editing

I selected the vertices, here in orange color. The pivot point is defined as "Median Point".
So, why is the circle center away from my selection?

What defines this center?

[image: Here the center of rotation :]
[image: Here the sphere of influence :]

Thank you,

Comment: You may want to show more of the screen to convince the viewer the center of rotation is where you would like it.  You may want to press [.] on the numeric keypad to ensure the selection is only what is depicted above.  Or make a new selection for a fresh experiment/investigation ... as in deselect all.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post with an image showing the center of rotation

Comment: I don't know whether it has any effect in proportional editing, but you also have the Transform Orientation set to Local rather than Global. Also scroll out more in case there is something selected below the screen that you can't see.

Comment: Looks like you're editing a mesh which is deformed by a modifier (probably an armature modifier). The drawing of the circle of proprtional editing stays where it would be in edit mode without modifiers, but its behaviour will be the expected one.